# How to reset values over a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a `YAML` file which can't be committed to my repository because contains password and sensible information. It looks like this:

```
devops:
  branch: somebranch

password:
  provider:
    digital_ocean:
      token:
        ""
    aws:
      bob:
        access_key_id:
          "XXX"
        secret_access_key:
          "XXX"
      jim:
        access_key_id:
          "XXX"
        secret_access_key:
          "XXX"
  dev:
    bob:
      "secret"
    jim:
      "another secret"
  app:
    mom:
      zookeeper:
        "XXX"
      admin:
        "XXX"
```

I'm trying to develop a script in `Python` were I can *clear all the passwords* in this my file. And this I can commit into my repository, it should look like this after being processed:

```
devops:
  branch: somebranch

password:
  provider:
    digital_ocean:
      token:
        ""
    aws:
      bob:
        access_key_id:
          ""
        secret_access_key:
          ""
      jim:
        access_key_id:
          ""
        secret_access_key:
          ""
  dev:
    bob:
      ""
    jim:
      ""
  app:
    mom:
      zookeeper:
        ""
      admin:
        ""
```

I know that is possible to set values into dictionaries like this:

```
import os
import yaml

with open(os.environ['DEVOPS_HOME'] + "/vagrant/server/settings.yml") as f:
    settings = yaml.load(f)

for key in settings.keys():
    settings[key]=0
```

However, this is my output:

```
{'password': 0, 'devops': 0}
```

Is there a way to iterate over my dictionary and set the values for my passwords only? Or should I change the structure of my YAML file?

Comment: Can you iterate only over the keys of the password section?

Comment: I'm trying to do that @S.deMelo, but I don't know how. I'm new to Python. Can you show me how is done with an example, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys for which the values need "wiping" don't seem to have a regularity in naming, but the one thing that they seem to have in common is that they are all the leaf-values under key password. That makes recursion an option to wipe them all without specifying each full key path ¹:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
nas:
devops:
  branch: somebranch

password:
  provider:
    digital_ocean:
      token:
        ""
    aws:
      bob:
        access_key_id:
          "XXX"
        secret_access_key:
          "XXX"
      jim:
        access_key_id:
          "XXX"
        secret_access_key:
          "XXX"
  dev:
    bob:
      "secret"
    jim:
      "another secret"
  app:
    mom:
      zookeeper:
        "XXX"
      admin:
        "XXX"
"""

def wipe_pass(data, key):
    """wipe the value if it is a string instance"""
    if isinstance(data[key], type("")):
        data[key] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString("")
        return
    if isinstance(data[key], dict):
        for k in data[key]:
            wipe_pass(data[key], k)
        return
    raise NotImplementedError   # e.g. a YAML sequence

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str, preserve_quotes=True)
wipe_pass(data, 'password')
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
devops:
  branch: somebranch

password:
  provider:
    digital_ocean:
      token: ""
    aws:
      bob:
        access_key_id: ""
        secret_access_key: ""
      jim:
        access_key_id: ""
        secret_access_key: ""
  dev:
    bob: ""
    jim: ""
  app:
    mom:
      zookeeper: ""
      admin: ""
```

please note that your original YAML has inconsistent formatting of key-value pairs, where the value is not a mapping. Here the output is consistent with your original `branch: somebranch` pair.

The `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString("")` is necessary to get `""` as output. If you just assign `""`, you'll get the default `''` single quotes for the empty string in your YAML file.

You can try to do the above with PyYAML, but you will lose any comments, have non-guaranteed key ordering, lose the empty line before `password:` and probably more. That makes it largely unusable for round-tripping data (load, modify, dump) that has to have minimal changes between commits.

---

¹ <sub>This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) a YAML 1.2 parser, of which I am the author.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anthon!

Comment: I think you meant `wipe_pass` instead of `clean_pass` inside the `wipe_pass` function.

Comment: @xZise Yes, thanks for pointing out. I renamed it after pasting in to confirm to the commentary terminology that I used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually set each string in the password section to be an empty string. For example if your dictionary is the following:

```
{
    'public_stuff': 'this should not be changed',
    'password':
    {
        'category1':
         {
            'user': 'password'
         },
         'other_user': 'other_password',
    },
}
```

You can do this recursively in a function which clears all string values. If it comes to a dictionary value, it executes the function on that value itself.

```
def clear_password(content):
    for key in content:
        if isinstance(content[key], str):
            content[key] = ""
        elif isinstance(content[key], dict):
            clear_password(content[key])

clear_password(settings["password"])
```

In Python 2, `str` might need to be `basestring` or `unicode`.